# Dealing with 'remainder' elements

Tags: ruby

Given an array `names` (length unknown), create working groups of 4, no working group can be less than 3! UNLESS the array only has one, or two names contained with in.

**CODE**

```
 def groups(source)
   Hash[ source.each_slice(4).map.with_index { |key, value| [ "Group: #{value+1}", key] } ]
 end
```

**Examples**

```
names10 = ["Aname", "Bname", "Cname", "Dname", "Ename", "Fname", "Gnames", "Hnames",
           "Inames", "Jnames"]

puts groups(names10)
 #=> {"Group: 1"=>["Aname", "Bname", "Cname", "Dname"], "Group: 2"=>["Ename", "Fname",
 #    "Gnames", "Hnames"], "Group: 3"=>["Inames", "Jnames"]}
```

As you can see from the example above, my code created a group 3 with two names. Desired return would be to take the names in group 3 and distribute them in group 1 and group 2.

**Expected return**

```
puts groups(names10)
 #=> {"Group: 1"=>["Aname", "Bname", "Cname", "Dname", "Jnames",], "Group: 2"=>["Ename",
 #    "Fname", "Gnames", "Hnames", "Jnames"]}
```

If the array contained 26 names, my code would return 6 groups of 4 and 1 group of 2, I would like to be able to take the two names in group 7 and distribute them between group 5 and 6.

I hope this clarifies my question. and yes my code before was broke! sorry

Comment: Do correct punctuation and formatting. Your question is rude to the readers.

Comment: Write what you want before writing your broken code.

Comment: is this better, I don't want to be rude.. also, the code that I posted.. does work, I'm asking how to improve the code to get my desired output.

Comment: Please provide the *expected output* from your corpus. It's almost impossible to tell what you think the result should look like just from your prose description.

Comment: So you actually want 2 groups because `10/4` leaves a remainder, right? What if you had 11 elements or 13 elements?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: If my understanding of your question is correct, please feel free to copy and paste it into your question, making clear that it is an edit (e.g., Edit: .... ). If my understanding is not correct, and it would be helpful, modify my wording as required. If you do not clarify your question soon, it will be closed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please keep in mind that this is not a code-generation service for your school assignments.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand you question, but I will offer an answer to the following one:

*"Given an array `a` and a minimum subarray size `m`, `1 < m <= a.size`, return an array `b = [b1, b2,.., bf]` that partitions the elements of `a` into subarrays `bi, i=1..f` such that the subarrays are all of size `s`, where `s >= m`, and `s` is as small as possible."*

..and then I will turn the returned array into the hash you requested.

**Code**

```
def equal_partition(arr,min_sub_size)
  as = arr.size
  sz = (min_sub_size..as).find { |sub_size| (as % sub_size).zero? }
  arr.each_slice(sz).map.with_index(1) { |a,i| ["Group: #{i}:", a] }.to_h
end
```

**Examples**

```
names10 = ["Aname", "Bname",  "Cname",  "Dname",  "Ename",
           "Fname", "Gnames", "Hnames", "Inames", "Jnames"]

equal_partition(names10, 3)
  #=> {"Group: 1:"=>["Aname", "Bname",  "Cname",  "Dname",  "Ename"],
  #    "Group: 2:"=>["Fname", "Gnames", "Hnames", "Inames", "Jnames"]}
equal_partition(names10, 2)
  #=> {"Group: 1:"=>["Aname", "Bname"], "Group: 2:"=>["Cname",  "Dname"],
  #    "Group: 3:"=>["Ename", "Fname"], "Group: 4:"=>["Gnames", "Hnames"],
  #    "Group: 5:"=>["Inames", "Jnames"]}
equal_partition(names10, 6)
  #=> {"Group: 1:"=>["Aname", "Bname",  "Cname",  "Dname",  "Ename",
  #                  "Fname", "Gnames", "Hnames", "Inames", "Jnames"]}
equal_partition(names10, 1)
  #=> {"Group: 1:"=>["Aname"],  "Group: 2:"=> ["Bname"],
  #    "Group: 3:"=>["Cname"],  "Group: 4:"=> ["Dname"],
  #    "Group: 5:"=>["Ename"],  "Group: 6:"=> ["Fname"],
  #    "Group: 7:"=>["Gnames"], "Group: 8:"=> ["Hnames"],
  #    "Group: 9:"=>["Inames"], "Group: 10:"=>["Jnames"]}
```

.

```
names12 = ["Aname", "Bname",   "Cname",  "Dname",  "Ename", "Fname",
           "Gnames", "Hnames", "Inames", "Jnames", "Kname", "Lname"]

equal_partition(names12, 3)
  #=> {"Group: 1:"=>["Aname",  "Bname",  "Cname"],
  #    "Group: 2:"=>["Dname",  "Ename",  "Fname"],
  #    "Group: 3:"=>["Gnames", "Hnames", "Inames"],
  #    "Group: 4:"=>["Jnames", "Kname",  "Lname"]}

equal_partition(names12, 4)
  #=> {"Group: 1:"=>["Aname",  "Bname",  "Cname",  "Dname"],
  #    "Group: 2:"=>["Ename",  "Fname",  "Gnames", "Hnames"],
  #    "Group: 3:"=>["Inames", "Jnames", "Kname",  "Lname"]}

equal_partition(names12, 5)
  #=> {"Group: 1:"=>["Aname",  "Bname",  "Cname",  "Dname",  "Ename", "Fname"],
  #    "Group: 2:"=>["Gnames", "Hnames", "Inames", "Jnames", "Kname", "Lname"]}

equal_partition(names12, 6)
  #=> {"Group: 1:"=>["Aname",  "Bname",  "Cname",  "Dname",  "Ename", "Fname"],
  #    "Group: 2:"=>["Gnames", "Hnames", "Inames", "Jnames", "Kname", "Lname"]}
```

**Explanation**

Suppose we wish to calculate:

```
equal_partition(names10, 3)
```

then

```
arr = names10
min_sub_size = 3
as = arr.size

sz = (min_sub_size..as).find { |sub_size| (as % sub_size).zero? }
  #=> (3..10).find { |sub_size| (10 % sub_size).zero? }
  #=> 5

enum1 = arr.each_slice(5)
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["Aname",  "Bname",  "Cname",  "Dname", "Ename",
  #         "Fname", "Gnames", "Hnames", "Inames", "Jnames"]:each_slice(5)>
enum2 = enum1.map
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: ["Aname", "Bname", "Cname", "Dname",
  #         "Ename", "Fname", "Gnames", "Hnames", "Inames",
  #         "Jnames"]:each_slice(5)>:map>
enum3 = enum2.with_index(1)
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: ["Aname", "Bname",
  #         "Cname", "Dname", "Ename", "Fname", "Gnames", "Hnames",
  #         "Inames", "Jnames"]:each_slice(5)>:map>:with_index(1)>
```

`enum2` and `enum3` can be thought of as "compound" enumerators. We can convert `enum3` to an array to see what (two) objects it will pass into its block:

```
enum3.to_a
  #=> [[["Aname", "Bname",  "Cname",  "Dname",  "Ename"],  1],
  #    [["Fname", "Gnames", "Hnames", "Inames", "Jnames"], 2]]

a = enum3.each { |a,i| ["Group: #{i}:", a] }
  #=> [["Group: 1:", ["Aname", "Bname",  "Cname",  "Dname",  "Ename"]],
  #    ["Group: 2:", ["Fname", "Gnames", "Hnames", "Inames", "Jnames"]]]

a.to_h
  #=> {"Group: 1:"=>["Aname", "Bname",  "Cname",   "Dname", "Ename"],
  #    "Group: 2:"=>["Fname", "Gnames", "Hnames", "Inames", "Jnames"]}
```

For versions of Ruby prior to 2.0, the last step must be replaced with:

```
Hash[a]
```

Comment: thanks for this!!! but this isn't what I was after. Your solution assumes two arguments, I will only get one argument, the array of names. I have modified my question and my code to help **hopefully** clarify what I'm after.